# Use SPL Enum with PHP7 from PPA

Tags: php, build, php-extension, spl

I am using the PPA for PHP7 from here: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php-7.0

My OS ist Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-Bit.

How can I use or build the SPL types extension? For example the PDO DBLIB extension was build without problems. But this one is too tricky for me ;-)

After downloading php-7.0.2 source I go to dir ext/spl and do phpize, ./configure, make and then sudo make install.

make is only running a millisecond but without errors. But there is no module in ext/spl/modules. After make install I only get the message "no file found" or similar.

Has anyone a solution? It is very important for me because I am a heavy user of this extension.

Kind regards,
dvlpr

Comment: ext/spl is the main SPL extension, which is always compiled in. SPL enums are not part of SPL (despite the name). They are a PECL extension.

Comment: Ok.That's right - I see it in phpinfo();
That was the wrong start.

But i still need SplEnum. Is it possible to use it for PHP7 already? I cannot find any information about.

Comment: Doesn't seem so. Here's the repo (it's even still using SVN, wow): http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/spl_types/